# Vonage\Client\Credentials\Basic not found

Tags: laravel-6, sms-gateway, vonage

if i am create new Laravel 6 project and then run this composer require vonage/client and after paste this code

```
$basic  = new \Vonage\Client\Credentials\Basic(******, ********);
$client = new \Vonage\Client($basic);
```

it working fine but if i doing same thing on old project its not working.
If anyone knows this solution let me know, please.